# Dynamically handling different version of protocol

Tags: go, interface, package

I have to handle multiple versions of communication protocol. I have packages with all packets and their IDs which look like

```
package v1_8

//Clientbound packet IDs
const (
    KeepAliveClientbound byte = iota
    JoinGame
    ChatMessageClientbound
    TimeUpdate
    EntityEquipment
    SpawnPosition
    UpdateHealth
    Respawn
    PlayerPositionAndLookClientbound
    HeldItemChangeClientbound
    UseBed
    AnimationClientbound
    SpawnPlayer
    CollectItem
...
```

and

```
package v1_14_3

//Clientbound packet IDs
const (
    SpawnObject byte = iota //0x00
    SpawnExperienceOrb
    SpawnGlobalEntity
    SpawnMob
    SpawnPainting
    SpawnPlayer
    AnimationClientbound
    Statistics
    BlockBreakAnimation
    UpdateBlockEntity
    BlockAction
    BlockChange
    BossBar
    ServerDifficulty
    ChatMessageClientbound
    MultiBlockChange
...
```

There are slight differences between versions (different IDs for the same packets or changed type of data) how do I go about handling them? For now, I am just using switch statement to check what packet is being processed but that works only for one version. I have information about client protocol version so I just need to change package that is being used in switch statement.

```
for {
    pkt, err := src.ReadPacket()
    if err != nil {
        ...handle error
    }

    switch pkt.ID {
    case v1_14_3.<Packet Const>:
        ...handle packet - there might be different data type assigned for different versions of protocol
    }

    err = dst.WritePacket(pkt)
    if err != nil {
        ...handle error
    }
}
```

@Edit: providing more information

Package struct returned by `ReadPacket()`

```
type Packet struct {
    ID   byte
    Data []byte
}
```

And some real-life data

```
{0 [234 3 9 108 111 99 97 108 104 111 115 116 99 156 1]}
```

This is one of the packets defined [here](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshake) as Handshake

I then use `Scan` method of `Packet` struct like this

```
switch pkt.ID {
case v1_14_3.Handshake:
    var (
        protocolVersion packet.VarInt
        serverAddress   packet.String
        serverPort      packet.UnsignedShort
        nextState       packet.VarInt
    )
    err = pkt.Scan(&protocolVersion, &serverAddress, &serverPort, &nextState)
    if err != nil {
        ...handle error
    }
    ...process packet
}
```

As I said before types passed to `Scan` method can be slightly different for different versions as well as packets IDs. So `Handshake` packet between versions may have different `pkt.ID` or different payload (therefore properties passed to scan would be different). `Scan` is just variadic function that propagates passed variables with `pkt.Data`

Comment: Plese provide some more info convering how the packets are being encoded. For example what does ```ReadPacket()``` return? (details of the structs returned is probably more useful than the consts). An example of two 'packets' (real data) that you are trying to seperate would help to clarify things.

Comment: I edited my question and added some more information and examples. Thank you for suggesting that.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info (from the link it looks like you are decoding minecraft packets; stating this and saying what your end goal is would help clarify this further). Currently I'm still not really clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Based on what you have said my initial thought would be to encapuslate protocol encoding/decoding in your protocol specific packages (e.g. ```v1_14_3```) and have these provide a standard interface your main routine can access (but this is a guess based on very limited info).

Comment: Yes I am decoding Minecraft packets. My goal is to make proxy that will analyze packets sent between user and server that will work with any protocol version. So just one binary as a drop-in for any supported minecraft/protocol version. I am sorry that maybe I cannot clearly explain what am I trying to accomplish but English is not my first language.

Comment: I was thinking about making standard interface for each packet and then handling it and returning from protocol specific package but that just seems like a lot of boilerplate writing this for tens or even hundreds of packets for every version which will add up pretty quickly.

Comment: I relly don't see any way around this if you want to extract a large amount of the info. There are a range of strategies you could follow - have you looked at [protodef](https://github.com/ProtoDef-io/ProtoDef)? (this might give you some idea as to how much work this will be).